# How to Inserting string after matching pattern

Tags: regex, perl, shell, sed

I need to insert a debugging instruction after every `catch` in a project that contains thousands of PHP files.

I want to match the pattern

`catch (`

So that after every matching pattern, I want to insert the instruction:

`Reporter::send_exception($e);`

I've been trying to use sed to accomplish this, but I haven't been able to succeed.

This is the sed command that I'm using:

`sed -e '/catch \(/{:a,n:\ba;i\Reporter::send_exception\(\$e\);\g' -e '}' RandomFile.php`

Any help writing this will be greatly appreciated!

I've seen other solutions for the same problem here in Stack Overflow, but none of those solution have worked either.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Basically my files will look like pretty much like this:

```
try {
  do_something();
} catch ( AnyKindOfException $e) {
  Reporter::send_exception($e); // Here's where I want to insert the line
  // throws generic error page
}
```

That's why I want to match `catch \(*$`
and after that insert
`Reporter::send_exception($e)`

Comment: Don't escape the parens

Comment: Are you inserting on the same line right after the matching pattern, or do you want to insert on the next line?

Comment: I want to insert on the next line, I'll edit my question to provide more context

Comment: `sed`'s `i` command inserts text on the line before the one matching the pattern, so it's definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want to insert the text after the line containing `catch (`.

Under `perl -p`, `$_` contains the line read, and whatever `$_` contains after the code is executed will be printed. So we just append the line to insert to `$_` when appropriate.

```
perl -pe'$_.="  Reporter::send_exception(\$e);\n" if /catch \(/'
```

or

```
perl -pe's/catch\(.*\n\K/  Reporter::send_exception(\$e);\n/'
```

Usage:

```
perl -pe'...' file.in >file.out    # From file to STDOUT
perl -pe'...' <file.in >file.out   # From STDIN to STDOUT
perl -i~ -pe'...' file             # In-place, with backup
perl -i -pe'...' file              # In-place, without backup
```

Comment: I was wondering why you didn't concatenate with a newline in front, then I remembered that Perl retains the newline from each line.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `sed \a` command which allows you to append the line. Syntax is:

```
sed '/PATTERN/ a\
    Line which you want to append' filename
```

So in your case it would be:

```
sed '/catch (/ a\
Reporter::send_exception($e);' filename
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat fff
adfadf
afdafd
catch (
dfsdf
sadswd

$ sed '/catch (/ a\
Reporter::send_exception($e);' fff
adfadf
afdafd
catch (
Reporter::send_exception($e);
dfsdf
sadswd
```

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
sed 's/catch (/\0Reporter::send_exception($e);/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
sed -e 's/catch\s*(/catch (\n\tReporter::send_exception($e);/'
```